# Deleting d3 graph nodes leaves lines remaining

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, directed-graph

I'm writing a basic directed graph editor and loading the initial graph from JSON.

My issue is that deleting nodes frequently leaves lines remaining (often completely unrelated to the node I'm removing - You can replicate this by going through and deleting a bunch of nodes). The remaining artifacts do not move with the force layout either.

My understanding is that `link.exit().remove();`
should remove any links that do not match my current dataset:

```
link = link.data(links,function(d){return d.source.Id + "_" + d.target.Id;});
```

A link to my sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/slizice/9a8d6zsm/60/
(click a node and hit `delete`/`backspace` to remove)

I didn't observe this until I started working with larger datasets.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

Looks like some duplicate links might be responsible. I'll post up an answer once I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my server-side code which generates links traverses them multiple times in some cases, generating duplicates.

To handle duplicates on the client side, I simply check the array first:

```
exists = false;
  edges.forEach(function(e) {
    if ((e.source.Id == sourceNode.Id) && (e.target.Id == targetNode.Id)) {
      exists = true;
    }
  });
  if (!exists) {
    edges.push({
      source: sourceNode,
      target: targetNode,
      value: e.Value
    });
  }
```